# Jquery - Stop auto complete of HTML tags when using .append

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a nested list from XML, however I find that the .append function seems to auto complete my HTML tags, useful agreed but how to I overide this operation when its not wanted OR is there a smarter way of doing the below:

```
$('#name').html('<li>'+'Origin'+'<ul>'+' ' ).html();
$(this).find("origin").each (function() {
var name = '<li>origin: ' + $(this).text() + '</li>';
$('#name').append(name);
$('#name').append('</ul></li>');
```

What I get:

```
<ul id="name">
<li>
Origin
<ul> </ul>
</li>
<li>origin: network</li>
<li>origin: nevil-nmshub</li>
<li>origin: origin_overide</li>
<li>origin: Support_4</li>
<li>origin: test-origin</li>
</ul>
```

As you can see its adding the   tags before I want them. I guess maybe I am going about this wrong, any advise?

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to the following:

```
var ul = $('<ul />');

// I believe you mean to find elements with class origin instead of <origin>
$(this).find(".origin").each (function() {
   var name = '<li>origin: ' + $(this).text() + '</li>';
   ul.append(name);
});
$('#name').append(ul);
```

Comment: it's actually `innerHTML` that does the magic - if you do `el.innerHTML = '<ul>'` and then query it back you'll get `<ul></ul>`

Comment: in that sense `.append()` _is_ equivalent to `.innerHTML += foo`

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys I almost got it doing what I need!

Answer (score 1):

`.append()` (as with `.innerHTML`) can only insert *entire DOM elements*, not incomplete snippets of arbitrary HTML.

So by definition the first time you `.append()` something, any tags therein will become implicitly closed.

Try this instead:

```
var $li = $('<li>').appendTo('#name');
var $ul = $('<ul>').appendTo($li);
$(this).find("origin").each(function() {
    $('<li>', { text: 'origin: ' + $(this).text() }).appendTo($ul);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are dynamically creating HTML, avoid separating the opening and closing tags as much as possible.

You can do it like this:

```
$('#name').append('<li>Origin<ul></ul></li>');

// I think 'origin' is an XML tag.
// So no worries, you can call in like an HTML element
$(this).find('origin').each(function(index, value) {
    $('#name ul').append('<li>origin: ' + value + '</li>')
});
```